# Кнопка редактирования записи в бд

Tags: php, mysql

Есть бд с таблицей 'people' в ней несколько полей, с помощью php на страницу выводятся все записи в таблице.
Вопрос в том, как после каждой записи добавить кнопку для её редактирования?
Также в таблице присутствует поле с типом set.

Answer (score 1):

сделай стр. например edit.php?id=id новости 
и на этой странице сделай форму в которой будешь в водить новые данные 
а запрос update юзай  для обновления данных в таблице
UPDATE news SET title = '$title',text = '$text' WHERE id = '$id');
Не забудь сделать проверку того кто заходи на страницу...

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: не за что! если что,можешь мне написать помогу сделать. 
malyshev.dev@ya.ru

Answer (score 0):

Для редактирования данных используйте [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php). На скорую руку, написать удачный и безопасный редактор таблиц БД врятли удастся.

Comment: Ну на "удачный" я и не расчитываю :) Просто требуется сделать подобную страничку с базой для человека, который не разберется phpmyadmin, а таблица в ворде уже отжила свое.